# "Flag External Email Warnings " is invalid. The value can't contain leading or trailing whitespace

Tags: html, powershell, exchange-server, rules

I need some help.... I'm currently working on adding this HTML code into exchange for a customer so that they can External Email Warning message for Office 365 Emails however every time I enter in the code and save, I receive this error message below.

```
"Error executing cmdlet: 
 |Microsoft.Exchange.Data.DataValidationException|Name: The property "Name" with value "Flag External Email Warnings " is invalid. The value can't contain leading or trailing whitespace.
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PSDirectInvoke.DirectInvokeCmdletExecutionException' was thrown."
```

Here is the code that I tried but won't work.

```
 "<p><div style="background-color:#FFEB9C; width:100%; border-style: solid; border-color:#9C6500; border-width:1pt; padding:2pt; font-size:10pt; line-height:12pt; font-family:'Calibri'; color:Black; text-align: left;"><span style="color:#9C6500"; font-weight:bold;>CAUTION:</span> This email originated from outside of the organization. Do not click links or open attachments unless you recognize the sender and know the content is safe.</div><br></p>"
```

Comment: What code do you use for setting up rules in Exchange?

Comment: As @EugeneAstafiev notes, you should show the code that sets up the rules, but the error message does spell out the immediate problem: The value `"Flag External Email Warnings "` has _trailing whitespace_.